# Passing var to regex with URL don't matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace some URLs with JS.
I don't get it, why the regex doesn't match here.
I've tested my expression on this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html
I'm getting a positive result here, but not in my own script.
Could anyone assist here?

```
var pattern = new RegExp("http://www\.example\.com/out/\?url=","g");
var context = "http://www.example.com/out/?url=http://google.com";
if(context.match(pattern))
{
    context = context.replace(pattern,"");
    alert(context);
}
else
    alert("no match");
```

Comment: Double escaping is required when using `new RegExp`. I guess on the site you were testing a regex literal. I.e `new RegExp("http://www\\.example\\.com/out/\\?url=","g")`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FA64L/

Comment: See [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Perfect. That's what I want. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a regex literal, then the following would be correct.

```
var pattern = /http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/out\/\?url=/;
```

When using `new RegExp`, the following would be correct

```
//var pattern = /http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/out\/\?url=/;
//var pattern = new RegExp("http:\\/\\/www\\.example\\.com\\/out\\/\\?url=");
var pattern = new RegExp("http://www\\.example\\.com/out/\\?url=");

var context = "http://www.example.com/out/?url=http://google.com";

if (context.match(pattern)) {
    context = context.replace(pattern, "");
    alert(context);
} else {
  alert("no match");
}
```

I haven't looked at the site link to see what they are doing with your input exactly.

But basically when using [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) you need to double escape anything that is escaped in the regexp literal. The escapes are not necessary for the `/` as they are only special when using literals.

Oh, and you don't need the `g` flag in your example.

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FA64L/)

Comment: delete the wrong escape on "\\/out\\/" and I can accept it as the correct answer

Comment: It was the correct escape, just shouldn't have been in the example like that. :)

Comment: Oh, and there is probably a much nicer way of doing this without a regex, if the URL is always the same. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6hPMV/

Comment: There are many possible solutions for it, when the URL is always the same. But I like the current way ;)